# Unable to reach json server from fetch in react native app

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-native

I am unable to fetch data from JSON server using the fetch method even I am using the IP address in URL (http://192.168.1.121:3001/).

Its showing error "Network request failed" when I am trying to fetch using react native app but I can access the server using "http://localhost:3001/" in my browser.

I searched a lot on google, everyone is saying use an IP address instead of localhost, I tried this too but still no response from the server.

Please help me to sort it out it would be great for me.
Thankx!

Answer (score 4):

I solved it out by starting my server by providing IP to it...

```
json-server --watch db.json -p 3001 -d 2000 --host 192.168.1.121
```

Comment: Good job - glad you fixxed it.

Comment: I am wondering. does this works for production as well?

Comment: Ive done this + change the fetch statement to IP instead of localhost but still does not work...

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the IP Address of your PC? it has to be the IP Address from your Pc where you are developing your App - if you are running it on an Emulator. Check your Network Config on your PC and take the IPV4 Address and try that.

Comment: Yes, I am already using it but still no response from server

Comment: if you have an rest api like /api/user/info or something try a full request - or try to use postman its a cool tool to do get and post requests. If the Ip is correct then the error must be somewhere else maybe :3001 is wrong or something. I had problems with this too but after using my PC IP everything worked.